# Insert Array(s) of Data into SQL using AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, performance

I am trying to insert an array(s) of data into SQL using AJAX and PHP. The array is built in Javascript and passed into PHP which a SQL statment grabs the data. It is supposed to insert the data, but it is not inserting.

In my PHP, I declared 6 variables and inserted random data to test to see if the query and the data was working; and it does. It's when I use the 'SqlArr' for my values that dont insert. How do I insert an array of data that i am dynamically pushing into the SQL database using AJAX and PHP?

Any help is most appreciated.

JavaScript:

```
            var cnt=0;  
            Empdata = 'EmpData' + cnt + '';
            temp={EmpId,WeekEnding,DateOccur,JobNum, Customer, HourValue};
            SqlArr.push({Empdata : temp});
```

PHP

```
<?php
include_once 'DbConnectPSI.php';
    global $connect;
    global $record3;
    global $myData3;
    global $var1;
    global $var2;
    global $var3;
    global $var4;
    global $var5;
    global $var6;

    $var1=2;
    $var2=2015-09-12;
    $var3=2015-09-09;
    $var4=2;
    $var5=2;
    $var6=55;


    $SqlArr =$_POST['SqlArr'];

    $myData3="Insert Into EmployeeTimesheets  Values('$SqlArr', getDate())";    
    //$myData3="Insert Into EmployeeTimesheets  Values('$var1','$var2','$var3','$var4','$var5','$var6', getDate())";    

    $record3 = odbc_exec($connect, $myData3);


    odbc_close($connect);
    ?>
```

Data comming from Javascript and into the SqlArr.push

> EmpId=2, WeekEnding=2015-09-12, DateOccur=2015-09-09, JobNum=2,
>   Customer=2, HourValue=55

`
    Table structure using Sql Server 2008 R2

```
 USE [xx]
    GO

    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeTimeSheets](
        [PkId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [EmpId] [int] NULL,
        [WkEnd] [date] NULL,
        [Day] [date] NULL,
        [Title] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
        [Description] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [Value] [float] NULL,
        [TimeStamp] [datetime] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_EmployeeTimeSheets] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [PkId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
```

Array being received by PHP using var_dump

[image]

Comment: What is the structure of the EmployeeTimesheets table? Also what type of database is this?

Comment: just edited my post.. thanks for any help

Comment: Have you checked that you're receiving your data properly? i.e.: `var_dump($_POST['SqlArr']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not dump the whole array into SQL with a single interpolation like you are doing on this line:

```
$myData3="Insert Into EmployeeTimesheets  Values('$SqlArr', getDate())";
```

If you were to look at the value of `$myData3`, it would be:

> Insert Into EmployeeTimesheets  Values('Array', getDate())

I see that `$SqlArr` is also two-dimensional, with the first dimension just being a reference to the data that you actually want to work with. So before anything else, you probably want to do this:

```
$SqlArr = $SqlArr[0];
```

Then instead of trying to interpolate the entire array, you need to reference the individual array items, like this:

```
$myData3="Insert Into EmployeeTimesheets  "
    + "Values('$SqlArr[EmpId]', '$SqlArr[WeekEnding]', getDate())";
```

I've only included two of the items in the example, but you would include all of them.

You also should enumerate the columns in the `INSERT` statement to avoid problems in the future. Like this:

```
$myData3="Insert Into EmployeeTimesheets (EmpId, WkEnd) "
    + "Values('$SqlArr[EmpId]', '$SqlArr[WeekEnding]', getDate())";
```

Finally, you really shouldn't put the values directly into the SQL, but should use a parameterized query instead. I typically use PDO for database access, and a parameterized implementation of the insert looks something like this:

```
$sql = "Insert Into EmployeeTimesheets (EmpId, WkEnd) Values(?, ?, getDate())"; 
$conn = new PDO("connection string goes here");
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $SqlArr['EmpId']);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $SqlArr['WeekEnding']);
$stmt->execute();
```

You can also use named parameters if you prefer. See the [PDO documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).